# How do I fix things when the normal app uninstall process is failing on iOS?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-appstore

Of course, by holding down on an icon and tap the <kbd>x</kbd> lets me uninstall an app. But take a look at this:

[image]

Here, the Pandora app is somehow stuck at the "update phase". Tapping it to continue download doesn't work. The progress "circle" will get stuck. So I decided to reinstall it.

[image]

> Translation:
>   **Delete “”**
>   Deleting “” will also delete all its data.

For some reason it doesn't even show the name of the app. It's just blank.

Tapping <kbd>delete</kbd> does nothing. So what do I have to do to fix this problem?

Running iOS 8, not jail broken.

Answer (score 0):

Derek. Not a lot of people realize that an iPhone is a computer and should be treated as such. Just like your computer you shut it down or at least restart it on a regular basis. People don't do this with iPhones, because well, it's a phone and they may 'miss a call' or it's just habit for most. It causes a lot of memory leaks especially if developers aren't skilled enough to know how to test within their apps for memory leaks. In other words, a soft restart (turning it off in the normal manner by holding the sleep button and sliding to power off and then turning it back on) will 99% of the time autonomously repair itself and reset the memory. The 1% chance it does not you can do a hard restart (holding the sleep and home button simultaneously for 4-5 sec) will fix your issue.

Comment: I tried both way of turning off but the problem persists.

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫 you should consider a restore or just delete contents and settings? If you are using two different App Store (US and Europes) for example this could be the issue

Comment: I only have used the US App Store, but I'll try clearing the settings and data and see if it fixes the problem.

Answer (score -5):

Idk if it’d help but there is app for PC named 3utools (you can google it) and there is ability for deleting corrupted icon from homescreen. You need to connect phone to PC and delete icon from PC. I use this app but i didn’t tested yet this feature. I didnt saw yet a solution for doing that far away from home . Anyways - might help.

Comment: ? ey, why it have -3 ?